# Isn't $x^2+1 $ irreducible in $\mathbb Z$, then why is $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Isn't $  x^2+1$  irreducible in $\mathbb Z$, then why is $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$?

$  x^2+1$ cannot be broken down further non trivially in $\mathbb Z[x]$. hence, it's irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Hence, shouldn't $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ be a field and hence,  $ x^2+1$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your «hence» is just not true: it is true that if $K$ is a field and $p\in K[x]$ is irreducible, then $K[x]/(p)$ is a field. Yet $\mathbb Z$ is not a field.

Comment: For the same reason that $(x)$ isn’t a maximal ideal.

Comment: Got it. I completely forgot the fact that $Z$ is not a field. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the quotient is not a field, as you can easily check!

For example, the class of $2$ is neither zero nor invertible in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Yes, I was able to confirm that the quotient is not a field. But, we have a theorem that : Let $F$ be a field and let $p(x) \in F[x]$. then $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $F[x]$ if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z$ is not a field...

Comment: Ohhh :( .. I just lost it . Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 8):

More directly, the ideal $\langle x^2\!+\!1 \rangle$ is properly contained in the ideal $\langle x^2\! +\! 1, \ 3 \rangle$.  By definition, it cannot be maximal.

In particular, it is a theorem that no principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is maximal.  In fact, *all* maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $\langle p, f(x) \rangle$ where $p$ is prime and $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Glad I could help!